# Eigenvalues of $ST$ and $TS$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given linear transformations $S,T:V→V$, prove that if $x=0$ is an eigenvalue of $ST$, then it is an eigenvalue of $TS$.

Secondly, prove that if $y\neq 0$ is an eigenvalue of $ST$, and that if $v$ is eigenvector of $ST$ for $y$, then $Tv$ is an eigenvector of $TS$ for $y$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: In future please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: Anyone can help?

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer if you provide some context, such as showing any ideas you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this first part, there may be a simpler approach, but this is what came to mind. Since $ST$ has zero as an eigenvalue, we have
$$\det S \det T = \det ST = 0.$$
So, either $S$ or $T$ (or both) is singular. If $S$ is singular, take $v_0 \neq 0$ so that $Sv_0=0$. Then, 
$$TSv_0 = T\vec{0} = \vec{0}.$$
Suppose $T$ is singular. If $S$ is also singular, then, by the above, we are done. Suppose $S$ is not singular. Take $v_0 \neq 0$ so that $Tv_0 = 0$ and pick $w_0$ so that $Sw_0=v_0$.

For the next part,
$$TS(Tv) = T(STv) = T(yv) = yTv,$$
which implies that $Tv$ is an eigenvector of $TS$ with corresponding eigenvalue $y$.